# Has anyone tried improving SAP B1 DI API performance

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

SAP B1 DI-API performance can be quite slow when you are trying to import 200,000 records. It can take days.

I was wondering how we can improve the performance of DI API calls? Can I split my data and use different indirect user to connect to SAP and split the load? I believe threading is not an issue.

Have not tried threads yet, because I have been told it's not meant to be used with DI API. We are not using the DI Server.